# Checkboxes for objects in Parse.com´s data browser removed?

Tags: parse-platform

I´ve used Parse for two years now and have always been able to manually delete data objects directly in the data browser by checking the object checkbox and pressing the "Row-"-button.

Now I can't find the checkboxes? I´ve tried different apps and different browsers, does anyone knows anything about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logout and login doesn't work...

I found a temporary solution.
Open develop tools and uncheck width, height, opacity in styles for checkbox.
Then you can check rows as usual.

[image]

Comment: For those not familiar with "Open Develop tools and uncheck width..." can anyone make this a bit more explicit? Thanks kindly.

Comment: for mere html-mortals: so long as you can see the Develop menu option in Safari, select Show Web Inspector, then select Stylesheets in the Resource view once you are seeing the inspector. Open main.css, then search for "input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]" ..  i did not have selectable checkboxes as above, so i simply cut out the three lines and bamn, i have my checkboxes back.

Comment: Thank you and wtf parse?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. 
And now it's fixed.
Try logout and login.

Comment: Thanks for replying, this did not solve my problem though.

Comment: The problem happened again in my environment...

It's seems to be a new bug.   
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/NBxwtGl6Rxk